# Finding Maximum Concurrent Open Registers Per Day

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I have a table in a Sybase SQL Anywhere database of the following structure (non-essential fields removed) that is populated by retail store registers opening and closing during a business day. Many days of history are kept in the table, and at the start of the day a register's status is assumed to be closed. "OPENTILL" signifies opening a register for business, "CLOSETILL" signifies closing it:

```
Register   Transaction_Date      Transaction_Time     Transaction_Type
1          2013-02-25            08:00:00.000         OPENTILL
2          2013-02-25            08:01:00.000         OPENTILL
3          2013-02-25            08:02:00.000         OPENTILL
2          2013-02-25            09:00:00.000         CLOSETILL
3          2013-02-25            09:01:00.000         CLOSETILL
2          2013-02-25            10:00:00.000         OPENTILL
4          2013-02-25            11:00:00.000         OPENTILL
3          2013-02-25            12:00:00.000         OPENTILL
2          2013-02-25            13:00:00.000         CLOSETILL
1          2013-02-25            14:00:00.000         CLOSETILL
3          2013-02-25            15:00:00.000         CLOSETILL
4          2013-02-25            20:00:00.000         CLOSETILL
```

This is only sample data and the actual number of registers goes beyond 4. The data I'm looking to extract is the maximum number of concurrently open registers per day, i.e. a table like this:

```
Date             Max_Concurrent_Registers
2013-02-25       14
2013-02-24       9
2013-02-23       12
2013-02-22       8
```

Is it possible to do this with nothing more than fairly basic Sybase SQL -- i.e. aggregate functions, "WITH x AS (...)", sub selects, but no cursors or stored procedures?

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: and what is the condition for "concurrently open register"

Comment: cha - Registers start a given day in closed status. An "OPENTILL" record indicates that a register is open. The register will stay in that status until a "CLOSETILL" record for that same register is recorded. All registers are closed at the start of business day because a condition of closing off the previous business day is closing all registers. As indicated in the sample data, in our system the same register can be opened and closed multiple times in a day. Concurrently open registers is the number of registers in open status at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny, was involved in the discussion of a similar question the other day :)

```
SELECT transaction_date, MAX(concurrent_count)
  FROM ( SELECT transaction_date, Transaction_Time, Transaction_Type
               ,SUM( CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'OPENTILL' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END )
                OVER( PARTITION BY transaction_date
                      ORDER BY Transaction_Time ) AS concurrent_count
           FROM myTable
       ) x
   GROUP BY transaction_date
```

A sample run in Postgres:

```
postgres=# SELECT transaction_date, Transaction_Time, Transaction_Type
postgres-#                ,SUM( CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'OPENTILL' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END )
postgres-#                 OVER( PARTITION BY transaction_date ORDER BY Transaction_Time ) AS concurrent_count
postgres-#            FROM myTable;
 transaction_date | transaction_time | transaction_type | concurrent_count
------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------
 2013-02-25       | 08:00:00         | OPENTILL         |                1
 2013-02-25       | 08:01:00         | OPENTILL         |                2
 2013-02-25       | 08:02:00         | OPENTILL         |                3
 2013-02-25       | 09:00:00         | CLOSETILL        |                2
 2013-02-25       | 09:01:00         | CLOSETILL        |                1
 2013-02-25       | 10:00:00         | OPENTILL         |                2
 2013-02-25       | 11:00:00         | OPENTILL         |                3
 2013-02-25       | 12:00:00         | OPENTILL         |                4
 2013-02-25       | 13:00:00         | CLOSETILL        |                3
 2013-02-25       | 14:00:00         | CLOSETILL        |                2
 2013-02-25       | 15:00:00         | CLOSETILL        |                1
 2013-02-25       | 20:00:00         | CLOSETILL        |                0
(12 rows)


postgres=# SELECT transaction_date, MAX(concurrent_count)
postgres-#   FROM ( SELECT transaction_date, Transaction_Time, Transaction_Type
postgres(#                ,SUM( CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'OPENTILL' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END )
postgres(#                 OVER( PARTITION BY transaction_date ORDER BY Transaction_Time ) AS concurrent_count
postgres(#            FROM myTable
postgres(#        ) x
postgres-#    GROUP BY transaction_date;
 transaction_date | max
------------------+-----
 2013-02-25       |   4
(1 row)
```

Comment: This worked great. I did not initially mention that there were other transaction_types present in the table, but adding an extra WHEN-THEN clause to the CASE (OPENTILL is 1, CLOSETILL is -1, ELSE is 0) did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The optimal solution involves cumulative sums, but these are not supported in Sybase.

You can do the equivalent with a correlated subquery.  The basic idea is that the number of open tills at any time is the sum of the number of open tills minus the sum of the number of closed tills.  The final step is just to find the maximum:

```
select transaction_date, max(opentills)
from (select t.*,
             (select (sum(case when transaction_type = 'opentill' then 1 else 0 end) -
                      sum(case when transaction_type = 'closetill' then 1 else 0 end)
                     ) as NetOPens
              from transactions t2
              where t.transaction_date = t2.transaction_date
                    t2.transaction_time <= t.transaction_time
             ) as OpenTills
      from transactions t
    ) t
group by transaction_date
order by 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. This is a dense question, but where in this code is data selected from the original table? I read this as defining t and t2, with t2 being a subselect of t, but how is t being populated from the original table which I'll call "transactions"?

Comment: The original table is being accessed in the two `from` clauses.  The inner subquery renames this `t2` and the outer subquery keeps the name `t`.

Comment: I did not having any luck with this yesterday. I'm interpreting your most recent response to mean that I should change "t" to table name "transactions" everywhere. I thought I had done this and that SQL Anywhere was advising of an error on line 7 (t2.transaction_time <= t.transaction_time), specifically about t2. I'll give it another shot tonight.

Comment: @user1783979 . . . Perhaps the problem was that I inadvertently left out the `group by`.

Comment: @user1783979 . . . Glenn's answer is the better answer.  I didn't realize that Sybase supported cumulative sums.

Comment: There is an AND missing between the WHERE clauses. Execution was considerably longer than the cumulative sums method that you had mentioned was superior. Thanks for the contribution and for providing an alternative method.